# Rigid Body Simulations never work- everything flies in random directions

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I am so confused. I try to make a simple rigid body animation.

There is one piece in the middle which rotates and some other parts are connected to it and should move if the rotation is taking place.

However, if I start the animation, then everything just flies in random directions, even though i selected **Mesh** everywhere.

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you have all the collisions set to "mesh"?

Comment: wait nvm, that was a stupid question. lol

Comment: @Edgel3D, I thought it would be interesting to simulate the physics, but unfortunately blender is not capable for even such simple calculations. I also ended up animating it, but it would be interesting to see your solution with the constraint? Can you upload the blend file or show how you did it?

Comment: @Black I've done a better version of the example clip.  This one does it all automatically.  Have come in to post it as an answer anyway.  Blend file will be included.  Hope it suits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is rigged, not physic'd.  (I've treated it as a lock)

(Blend file below)

[image]

The bones are pulled in reverse to guarantee the locking shaft will move in a dead straight line.

To this end an Empty is animated to the left and is a parent for the shaft.  It's also an IK target for the bone that controls the middle linkage.

As it moves it pulls that bone across to effectively rotate the 1st child-bone that parents the disc, forcing it to rotate also.

It's all done back to front but as far as I can make out, it's the only practical way to guarantee the locking shaft won't vary from it's straight path.

As you've come to realise, Blender is an animator/modeller, not an engineering tool and does require some innovation to get around it's physics limitations at times.  It can be a marvelous brain stimulator!

[image]